# Laravel request->all() shows array with page url

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

I am sending a GET request to a route and I am getting back weird response when using

```
dd($request->all());
```

my route is

```
Route::get('{brand}/{type?}/{city?}', 'SearchController@index')->name('search');
```

my url is link/toyota?page=1 and the response back is

```
array:1 [▼
 "/toyota" => null
]
```

I would like to mention that it is working on localhost using serve, but I am hosting this on cpanel

***Edit*** : All query strings on my website does not work...

Comment: You cannot have two optional parameters following each other in your route

Comment: @Jerodev Works for me on localhost.
link/toyota/prius?page=2 works and link/toyota?page=1 works
but not on live server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem with htaccess...
Cpanel changed my htaccess

if anyone comes here for the same reason, the default laravel htaccess is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>


RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Mark your answer as accepted so other's would find it easily

Comment: @OluwatobiSamuelOmisakin Must wait two days... waiting until tomorrow